# Iframe content not loading properly in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 iframes in different 4 tabs. Content is getting cropped in Firefox but loading properly in Chrome. When I do reload Iframe content is getting loaded properly. But initially having problem.

Comment: Link to js fiddle for iframe -  Implemented iframe using below code
visit http://jsfiddle.net/YR4ne/4/

Comment: jsfiddle result is loading in all of my browser. Did u inspect it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I faced the same problem. The issue happened because initially we are hiding all the iframes except the first one. If you make any divisions as a display none, then your DOM will not refer the contents inside of them.

OK. Instead of using "display:none", you use "visibility:hidden". After this changes it will work. Becuase visibility hidden is just hide the visibility, but all DOM will load initially. But the problem is you can see the space occupation on that place.

**What I Did:**

Each and every tab onclick I have refreshed the particular div using jquery. Also I have moved the script on bottom the page. After that it was working fine for me.

Hopefully this idea will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you link screenshot of your issue?

Looks fine to me in every browser.

IE

[image]

Chrome

[image]

Mozilla FF

[image]

Comment: Use it in tab structure format. Like initially it will show first frame only.

Comment: sorry, I couldn't get u ?

Comment: on your solution, all the frames are visible right. He dont want like that. Initially he want to show one iframe only. He have some four links. On click of each link he want to show specific iframe on that place. Like tabs structure.